# Install PHP7 Servlet on Tomcat9

Tags: java, php, tomcat, servlets, integration

I'm trying to manually integrate PHP 7.1.11 with Tomcat 9 on a Windows 10 (x64). I tried to follow the tutorial using Pecl_5.2.5, but, the libraries were built on 32bit and are not loading:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Applications\PHP\php5servlet.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x501) on a AMD 64-bit platform
java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
net.php.reflect.loadLibrary(reflect.java:34)
net.php.reflect.<clinit>(reflect.java:29)
```

Is there any x64 binary to replace the php5servlet.dll(x32). Or even better. Is there a php7servlet.dll to integrate into my machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to do so, it seems that the libraries are not yet compiled for x64 -> PHP7 but I was able to use XAMPP and Apache (not tomcat). It may be useful if you don't need Java deployed.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/?source=typ_redirect